# Single hive query to extract a piece of string

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a column data "testdata" like this **`"NEW /abc/testapp/v1 POST/6.0"`** and I want to retrieve the output as **`"/abc/testapp/v1"`**

I am able to retrieve the data starting `(/abc/testapp/v1 POST/6.0)` like this

`select regexp_extract(testdata,'^(.*?)(?:/)(.*)$', 2) from tablename;`

But not sure how to strip the POST/6.0 part in the same query.Can someone please help here?

Comment: You should give more examples of input/output strings, in order to receive a potentially more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start from the first slash and take everything until the next space:

```
regexp_extract(testdata, '(/[^\\s]+)', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following

```
regexp_extract(testdata,'\\S+', 0, 2)
```

-

```
regexp_extract(testdata,'/\\S+', 0)
```

-

```
regexp_extract(testdata,'\\s+(\\S+)', 1)
```